# Get record from iCloud and save to Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, icloud

For saving to iCloud, I use the following code:

```
if let managedObjectContext = (UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate).managedObjectContext {

            restaurant = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObjectForEntityForName("Restaurant",
                inManagedObjectContext: managedObjectContext) as! Restaurant
            restaurant.name = nameTextField.text
            // some other code...

            var e: NSError?
            if managedObjectContext.save(&e) != true {
                println("insert error: \(e!.localizedDescription)")
                return
            }
        }
```

I saved record to local database and then use

```
saveRecordToCloud(restaurant)
```

to save this record to iCloud. But how to fetch this data from iCloud, and working with it like with core data? Like merging two databases into one